# Data usage stats using TrafficeStats and NetworkStatsManager

Tags: android

I developed Android app which gets data usage stats of all installed apps in a background service using TrafficStats API. Earlier this week, on Samsung Galaxy S5, after software update i.e. 6.0.1, TrafficStats returns always 0 for each uid. Same app is perfectly working on HUAWEI KIW-L21 and OS 6.0.1.

I got some posts of using NetworkStatsManager class for API 23 and above, some posts refer that this requires system level permissions.

I gone through documentation of NetworkStatsManager too.

Can anyone successfully implemented NetworkStatsManager for total and app-wise data usage?

Thanks in advance if someone really assist.

Answer (score 2):

So i will show both methods together that is using  **TrafficeStats** and **NetworkStatsManager**

I will get UID'S all the applications installed in the phone and use both ways to the the data usage.

you can refer this for a good example https://github.com/RobertZagorski/NetworkStats
Top 5 methods were taken from his code.

```
//when using NetworkStatsManager you need the subscriber id 
private String getSubscriberId(Context context, int networkType) {
  if (ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE == networkType) {
     TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     return tm.getSubscriberId();
     }
   return "";
}


// to get mobile data recived
public long getPackageRxBytesMobile(Context context,NetworkStatsManager networkStatsManager,int packageUid) {
  NetworkStats networkStats = null;
  networkStats = networkStatsManager.queryDetailsForUid(
                ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE,
                getSubscriberId(context, ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE),
                0,
                System.currentTimeMillis(),
                packageUid);
  NetworkStats.Bucket bucket = new NetworkStats.Bucket();
        networkStats.getNextBucket(bucket);
        networkStats.getNextBucket(bucket);
        return bucket.getRxBytes();
  }


// to get mobile data transmitted 
public long getPackageTxBytesMobile(Context context,NetworkStatsManager networkStatsManager,int packageUid) {
  NetworkStats networkStats = null;
  networkStats = networkStatsManager.queryDetailsForUid(
                ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE,
                getSubscriberId(context, ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE),
                0,
                System.currentTimeMillis(),
                packageUid);
  NetworkStats.Bucket bucket = new NetworkStats.Bucket();
  networkStats.getNextBucket(bucket);
  return bucket.getTxBytes();
}


// to get wifi data received 
public long getPackageRxBytesWifi(NetworkStatsManager networkStatsManager,int packageUid) {
  NetworkStats networkStats = null;
  networkStats = networkStatsManager.queryDetailsForUid(
                ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI,
                "",
                0,
                System.currentTimeMillis(),
                packageUid);
  NetworkStats.Bucket bucket = new NetworkStats.Bucket();
  networkStats.getNextBucket(bucket);
  return bucket.getRxBytes();
}


// to get wifi data transmitted 
public long getPackageTxBytesWifi(NetworkStatsManager networkStatsManager,int packageUid) {
  NetworkStats networkStats = null;
  networkStats = networkStatsManager.queryDetailsForUid(
                ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI,
                "",
                0,
                System.currentTimeMillis(),
                packageUid);
  NetworkStats.Bucket bucket = new NetworkStats.Bucket();
  networkStats.getNextBucket(bucket);
  return bucket.getTxBytes();
}


// print to log all the data usage value per application
public void printAllDataUsage(){
 PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
 // get all the applications in the phone
 List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

 NetworkStatsManager networkStatsManager = (NetworkStatsManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NETWORK_STATS_SERVICE);

 for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
     Log.d("MYLOG", String.valueOf(packageInfo.uid));
     Log.d("MYLOG", String.valueOf(packageInfo.name));
     Log.d("MYLOG", String.valueOf(packageInfo.packageName));

     // get data usage from trafficStats
     Log.d("MYLOG", String.valueOf(TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(packageInfo.uid)));
     Log.d("MYLOG", String.valueOf(TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(packageInfo.uid)));

     // get data usage from networkStatsManager using mobile
     Log.d("MYLOG", String.valueOf(getPackageRxBytesMobile(this,networkStatsManager,packageInfo.uid)));
     Log.d("MYLOG", String.valueOf(getPackageTxBytesMobile(this,networkStatsManager,packageInfo.uid)));

     // get data usage from networkStatsManager using wifi
     Log.d("MYLOG", String.valueOf(getPackageRxBytesWifi(networkStatsManager,packageInfo.uid)));
     Log.d("MYLOG", String.valueOf(getPackageTxBytesWifi(networkStatsManager,packageInfo.uid)));

  }
}
```